# Calling withdraw method with web3 ethereum

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

I'm calling a withdrawal method from a contract written in solidity from a react.js app using metamask. The transaction is failing and I don't know why. I think is something related to the gas fee because when I change it I get different errors. This is the react code:

```
     contract.methods
      .withdrawDividends()
      .send({
        from: userAddress,
        value: availableToWithdraw,
      })
      .on("transactionHash", function (hash: string) {
        console.log(hash);
      })
      .on(
        "confirmation",
        function (confirmationNumber: number, receipt: unknown) {
          console.log(confirmationNumber);
          console.log(receipt);
        }
      )
      .on("receipt", function (receipt: unknown) {
        // receipt example
        console.log(receipt);
      })
      .on("error", function (error: unknown, receipt: unknown) {
        // If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the second parameter will be the receipt.
        console.log(error);
        console.log(receipt);
      });
```

This is my solidity method:

```
function withdrawDividends() public {
    User storage user = users[_msgSender()];

    uint256 totalAmount = getUserDividends(_msgSender());

    require(totalAmount > 0, "User has no dividends");

    user.checkpoint = block.timestamp;

    (bool success, ) = _msgSender().call.value(totalAmount)("");
    require(success, "Transfer failed.");

    emit Withdrawn(_msgSender(), totalAmount);

}
```

The method is not crashing but I see the following error in metamask:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Is something related to the gas?

Comment: Does`getUserDividends(_msgSender())` return more than 0?

Comment: yes, if I don't send any value and gas: 28500000, it works but the withdraw is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your function to accept ETH value, it needs to have the `payable` modifier.

In your case:

```
function withdrawDividends() public payable {
```

You can read more about the `payable` modifier in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#receive-ether-function). It links to the `receive` function, which is a slightly different topic. But it also covers the `payable` modifier.